# How to filter a list with a blacklist in python

Tags: python

I'm hoping you can please help me with a problem I'm having. I have two lists: one with file paths and a second list with blacklisted terms. I essentially want to filter the list of file paths using a blacklist and print out the remaining (non-blacklisted) file paths. However, I can't seem to get it working. I suspect the nested for loops are causing the 'in' test to evaluate in a way I don't understand. Any help anyone can give me would be much appreciated.

Desired outcome:

```
filepaths = [
'/windows/bad_file1',
'/windows/bad_file2'
'/windows/good_file',
]

blacklist = [
'bad_file1'
'bad_file2',
]

for path in filepaths:
    for bad in blacklist:
        if bad not in path:
            print(path)

#prints /windows/good_file
```

However, currently I'm getting:

```
/windows/bad_file1
/windows/bad_file2/windows/good_file
/windows/bad_file1
/windows/bad_file2/windows/good_file
```

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your thoughtful (and prompt) responses! I really appreciate you taking the time to talk me through it.

Comment: When you say `if bad not in path`, that will only not print for the `bad` you are currently looking at.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path.basename` to compare the files with the blacklist as

```
import os

filepaths = [
'/windows/bad_file1',
'/windows/bad_file2',
'/windows/good_file'
]

blacklist = [
'bad_file1',
'bad_file2'
]
result = [file for file in filepaths if os.path.basename(file) not in blacklist]
print(*result)
```

Output

```
/windows/good_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the check for all the files and paths.

```py
for path in filepaths:
    flag = True
    for bad in blacklist:
        if bad in path:
            flag = False
            break
    if flag:
        print(path)
```

We use a `flag` boolean variable as a sort of switch to check if the specified file path contains any bad files. If there is even one bad file, we need to turn the switch off (`flag = False`), and it becomes no longer necessary to continue checking if the path contains other bad files. Therefore, we break from the loop.

If a file path does not contain any bad files, `flag` will remain `True` as it was originally initialized. Therefore, `if flag` will return `True`, and the program will proceed to printing the `path` variable inspected within the iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, You have missed the `,` in the list that you have created.

```
filepaths = [
'/windows/bad_file1',
'/windows/bad_file2',
'/windows/good_file'
]

blacklist = [
'bad_file1',
'bad_file2'
]
```

To get what you want..

```
import os

list(filter(lambda x: os.path.basename(x) not in blacklist, filepaths))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much more elegant way:

```
good_filepaths = [filepath for filepath in filepaths if not [bad for bad in blacklist if bad in filepath]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the most useful to me, as sometimes the term I want to blacklist is in the middle of the path, so the os.path.basename won't work. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem - accept the answer if it solves your problem. Good luck, fellow coder!

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that you are missing commas on some of your list and they are being treated as one string. Your loops are deeply complicated too. Unlike Perl you cannot return to outside loop easily when dealing with nested loops.

```
filepaths = [
'/windows/bad_file1',
'/windows/bad_file2', # missing comma here
'/windows/good_file',
]

blacklist = [
'bad_file1', # missing comma here
'bad_file2',
]


for path in filepaths:
  if not any(word in blacklist for word in path.split("/")):
      print(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

see what a short answer there is.

```
def blacklist_filter(p):
    return not any([i in p for i in blacklist])

print(list(filter(blacklist_filter, filepaths)))
```

or lambda

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: not any([i in x for i in blacklist]), filepaths)))
```

And you missed the commas in the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `all` and list-comprehension:

```
filepaths = [
'/windows/bad_file1',
'/windows/bad_file2',
'/windows/good_file',
]

blacklist = [
'bad_file1',
'bad_file2',
]

[i for i in filepaths if all(j not in i for j in blacklist)]
```

Comment: Why the downvote? (it helps if you could have at least given a rationale) 

Although I see @dirtybit suffered the same as well!

Comment: Thanks for balancing the scale! Upvoted yours too :)

Answer (score -1):

Fixing the missing commas in the Input lists, Using `split()` with indexing on each of the filename, and then check if it isn't present in the `blacklist`:

```
filepaths = [
'/windows/bad_file1',
'/windows/bad_file2',
'/windows/good_file'
]

blacklist = [
'bad_file1',
'bad_file2'
]


for elem in filepaths:
   if elem.split('/')[-1] not in blacklist:
       print(elem)
```

OUTPUT:

```
/windows/good_file
```

one-liner using `list-comprehension`:

```
print([x for x in filepaths if x.split('/')[-1] not in blacklist])
```